# Remote silent uninstall of NVDA

Tags: deployment, uninstall, silent

I deployed NVDA (https://www.nvaccess.org/) to Windows 10 machines using --install-silent, but now need to uninstall the software.
There is an uninstall.exe in the program file, but it doesn't appear to accept any silent flags. /? gives nothing.
When uninstall.exe runs, it unzips Au_.exe and uses it as the uninstaller, but I still can't find any silent uninstall flags.

Does anyone know how to silently remove NVDA?
Or, does anyone know what installer was used, and what flags might be able to be used to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the software uses Nullsoft, which creates uninstall.exe in the program folder (c:\program files (x86)\nvda\uninstall.exe), which accepts /S as a silent flag.
Remotely calling uninstall.exe /S successfully removed the software.